# Hot to design the ViewModel for a windows phone 8 pivot app

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 Pivot app using MVVM Light and I am wondering how to design my view model. Each pivot of the app (in total 3-4) work with different collections of data.

The options that I am considering are:

1. **Have one MainViewModel which contains the different collections for the different pivots.** The best practices that I read on MVVM all mandate (this is how I understood them at least) that one view should have one ViewModel so this option comes naturally.
2. **Have a separate ViewModel for each pivot and one MainViewModel to reference them.** This option makes more sense to me in terms of separation and code structure. It does make bindings and command wiring a little bit more tricky.

Which option would you say is better?

Comment: I'd personally go for the first one, as it makes handling tombstoning much easier. And you can easily switch to the second solution should your viewmodel become too complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have only one view model and then have separate collections for each viewmodel. Have necessary collection items to bind to pivot items.

View

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="TutoPivot" 
        SelectionChanged="PivotSelectionChanged">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Collection1.Title}">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0"
                SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged"
                LayoutMode="Grid"
                GridCellSize="150,150"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1.Items}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NewSoundTemplate}"
                                    />
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainModel
{
    public ItemViewModel Collection1 { get; set; }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        Collection1=CreateCollection();
```

Make the appropriate  data context.

Tutorial: [Data bound and pivot tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-10-Overview-of-the-Databound-App-and-Pivot-App-Project-Templates)